# Adding years in python return the wrong data

Tags: python, datetime

I am using `relativedelta` to add one year back to `datetime.now()`. However, the results seems to be strange.

`(datetime.now() - relativedelta(year=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`
returns `'0001-05-05'` which is supposed to be `'2021-05-05'`.

I am using python 3.9.12.

Is there a reported bug in `relativedelta`?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

```py
(datetime.now() - relativedelta(year=1))
```

means set the year to absolute value `1`, keeping everything else from `now()`

What you wanted was:

```py
(datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=1))
```

i.e. subtract one year from `now()`